# Get variable arguments directly from stack

Tags: c

I'm playing with the stack and function's call parameters.
What I want to achieve here is to get the value of variable parameters directly using the stack.

It works (or seems to work) fine when I don't use variable parameters.
Here is what is working:

```
void test(int a, int b)
{
  unsigned char *ptr;
  int i;

  ptr = (unsigned char*)&a;
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
      printf("%d,", *ptr);
    }    
}
```

That works, I can retrieve the value of b;
The same code using

```
void test(int a, ...);
```

as function's prototype doesn't work.

I cant understand what's going on here.

Can you help me?
Thanks !

Edit:
Ok, then it seeems there is no stable and reliable way to do that kind of stuff on my own. 
Lets say that in the callee function I know the data size (but not the type) of variable argument, is there a way to grab them ?

Comment: What you're doing is Undefined Behavior.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: How are you attempting to get the variable arguments? Tip - stdargs.h , va_start, va_arg, va_end.

Comment: @jweyric: I'm using gcc. I know i could use va_* macro, but that is purely expiremental, i'm just trying stuff to learn how it works :P

Comment: @Xaqq: Be aware the *stack layout* is not guaranteed to be the same across different compilers, or even with different compiling flags & optimisations.

Comment: Be even aware that there might be no stack at all. A stack is just one possible implementation of a function call convention. E.g on some architecture any reasonable number of arguments might be held in registers.

Comment: @arunkumar: It's `<stdarg.h>`, not `stdargs.h`.

Comment: In some sense it is probably better to mess around with assembly a little than to try to grok how a particular compiler implements this stuff. Or read the Crenshaw tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you know or can determine the number of arguments, you can use the macros from `<stdarg.h>`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void test1(int n, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int j = va_arg(args, int);
        printf("%d: %d\n", i, j);
    }
    va_end(args);
}

void test2(int a, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    int i = 0;
    printf("%d: %d\n", i++, a);
    va_start(args, a);
    int j;
    while ((j = va_arg(args, int)) > 0)
        printf("%d: %d\n", i++, j);
    va_end(args);
}
```

The difference is in how these two functions are called:

```
int main(void)
{
    test1(4, 1, 3, 7, 9);
    test2(1, 3, 7, 9, 0);
    return(0);
}
```

The `printf()` family uses an alternative but equivalent technique; those functions scan the format string and determine the type of each argument (as well as the number of arguments) from the information in the format string.  So, your main options are:

- count - `test1()`
- sentinel - `test2()`
- format string - `printf()`

Comment: The problem with your answer is that you're assuming that argument are of type int. In my case knowing the type of my argument are not an option.I know the the numbers and the size of them. How can I treat them as raw binary data ? Is there a way to do something like "data = va_arg(ap, get_size_from_somewhere()); That would be very usefull because I would be able to store those data as they are.

Comment: Idea: I could construct my raw data using int, looping with va_arg() for my_data_size / 4 + 1 iterations. But then, what about memory alignment or argument having a size of 1 or 2 bytes?

Comment: If you don't know, or cannot deduce, the type of the variables on the stack, you're stuck. You can't declare a local variable to hold the parameters, all else apart.  If you know the types, you can do it; I assumed a homogeneous list of integers because it was convenient. However you do it, the calling code must provide sufficient information to the called function that the called function knows the number and type (and  indirectly the size) or each parameter represented by the ellipsis ('`...`'). I have no idea what you mean by 'raw binary data'; treating them as uniformly `int` does that.

Comment: Alternatively, if you're really dealing with an array of bytes, pass the length of the array and a pointer to the start - but that does not require a variable number of arguments.

Comment: Well, let's say that i have `struct my_struct test`. That type is not know by the callee code at compile time. I would like to be able to store it in my `calle(sizeof(my_struct), test)` function. Problem is calle must be able receive any type of parameter (thas is why I use `...`), for exemple I must be able to do `calle(sizeof(int), 4)` or `calle(sizeof(char), 'a')`. calle function will store those data in a unsigned char array, for later use.

Comment: You will have to tell the called function how to interpret the arguments it is given, and ensure that it is only given arguments that it can interpret. Look at `printf()`; it can handle any basic type, but is not able to handle structures. I don't think anyone can write a function as you want. There are limits on the types that the `<stdarg.h>` can handle; the standard says: _The parameter type shall be a type
name specified such that the type of a pointer to an object that has the specified type can
be obtained simply by postfixing a * to type._  So, the called function must know the type.

Answer (score 1):

In functions with ... you can use va_* macro

```
void test(int a, ...) {
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, a);
  // Your code
  va_end(ap);    
}
```